# finding and replacing a pattern in a multiline file using python or bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

I have a text like this:

```
   \/::360::__/
    |::559:::|  |
 ::468::\:\~\:\ \/__/
 /:/\:\  /::390::\__\
::138::
  ::380::  /:/  \/__/
     /::144::\  \
    /::\ ::145:: \
::418::      ___
      ::539::___
     \|::483::__|
```

Here some pattern is made using `\` , `|` and `_`. Each line is added with a line number in the format `::539::`, etc in some random position. 
I want to first sort all the lines according to the line number given, and then scrap off the `**::line-number::**` from each line to obtain the actual flag.

( The actual question has 600 of these lines, randomly arranged. It was needed to arrange them with proper stripping to find the flag. )

[The actual complete text file link](https://bpaste.net/show/5379781c4ee8)

I have posted the python code I used as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# import sys
with open( 'sorted.txt'  ) as file:
    randlst =[0] * 600
    for line in file:
        num=''
        strng=''
        for each in line:
            if each.isdigit():
                num += each
            else:
                strng += each
        strng = strng.strip('::::')
        num = int(num)
        randlst.insert(num,strng)
    for i in range(600):
        if randlst[i] !=0:
            print(str(randlst[i]).replace('::::',''))
```

In this code, the file sorted.txt was produced after sorting the actual input file (given in link above) using bash because I thought sorting in python would become tough.

The problem is that the sorting done by bash was not completely accurate as you could see here:

```
      ::0:: ___
    ::1:: /\__\
     \/__::10::/
     /\  \::100::
    /::\ ::101:: \
   ::102::/:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\::103::  \
```

Due to this minor-seeming error, the final output didn't have a few letters and my submission was rejected.

Please point out how can I improve this (I don't have knowledge of regex, sorry for such a poor script).

Alternatively, can you suggest a bash command to do this work, rather than using python?

Comment: Please rephrase to make your needs clear. "first scrap off the ::linenumber:: part from each line, after sorting ..." Do you want the scrape first, or the sort? Is the sort ASCII or numeric based on the numbers? Close your parens, fix your spelling... You'll get much [better responses](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @PaulHodges.   Thanks for pointing that ambiguity in my doubt. I hope I have corrected the required part.

Comment: @jww . I actually wrote a python code myself but it didnt gave me a good result. The sorting and stripping was done but still some of them were not properly arranged as expected. 
Your idea is actually better. I will post the more accurate query here

Answer (score -1):

This will sort the lines according the number, and writes them to standard output (will substitute `::<number>::` for `''`):

```
data = r"""   \/::360::__/
    |::559:::|  |
 ::468::\:\~\:\ \/__/
 /:/\:\  /::390::\__\
::138::
  ::380::  /:/  \/__/
     /::144::\  \
    /::\ ::145:: \
::418::      ___
      ::539::___
     \|::483::__|"""


import re
for s1, _, s2 in sorted(re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?:::)(\d+)(?:::)(.*?)$', data, flags=re.M), key=lambda v: int(v[1])):
    print(s1 + s2)
```

Prints:

```
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   \/__/
    /:/  \/__/
 /:/\:\  /\__\
      ___
 \:\~\:\ \/__/
     \|__|
      ___
    |:|  |
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a python solution, that sorts the lines based on the embedded line number and then strips those numbers and prints the pattern

```
>>> print(s)
   \/::360::__/ 
    |::559:::|  | 
 ::468::\:\~\:\ \/__/ 
 /:/\:\  /::390::\__\ 
::138:: 
  ::380::  /:/  \/__/ 
     /::144::\  \ 
    /::\ ::145:: \ 
::418::      ___ 
      ::539::___ 
     \|::483::__| 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sorted_s ='\n'.join(sorted(s.splitlines(), key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0])))
>>> print (re.sub(r'::\d+::', '', sorted_s))

     /\  \ 
    /::\  \ 
   \/__/ 
    /:/  \/__/ 
 /:/\:\  /\__\ 
      ___ 
 \:\~\:\ \/__/ 
     \|__| 
      ___ 
    |:|  | 
>>>
```

On trying this on the contents of page `https://bpaste.net/raw/5379781c4ee8` user G_M has created, this is what we get

```
>>> import requests
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> r = requests.get('https://bpaste.net/raw/5379781c4ee8')
>>> s = r.text
>>> sorted_s ='\n'.join(sorted(s.splitlines(), key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0])))
>>> print (re.sub(r'::\d+::', '', sorted_s))
      ___
     /\__\
    /::|  |
   /:|:|  |
  /:/|:|__|__
 /:/ |::::\__\
 \/__/~~/:/  /
       /:/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\__\____
 /:/\:::::\__\
 \/_|:|~~|~
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
     \|__|

      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
     /::\__\
  __/:/\/__/
 /\/:/  /
 \::/__/
  \:\__\
   \/__/

      ___
     /\__\
    /::|  |
   /:|:|  |
  /:/|:|  |__
 /:/ |:| /\__\
 \/__|:|/:/  /
     |:/:/  /
     |::/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/_\:\__\
 \:\  /\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/











      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\ \  \
  _\:\~\ \  \
 /\ \:\ \ \__\
 \:\ \:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/ \:\__\
 \:\  \  \/__/
  \:\  \
   \:\  \
    \:\__\
     \/__/

      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
     /::\__\
  __/:/\/__/
 /\/:/  /
 \::/__/
  \:\__\
   \/__/


      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
     /::\__\
  __/:/\/__/
 /\/:/  /
 \::/__/
  \:\__\
   \/__/












      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/_|::\/:/  /
    |:|::/  /
    |:|\/__/
    |:|  |
     \|__|
      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
      \:\  \
      /::\  \
     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /
   \/__/














      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
     /::\__\
  __/:/\/__/
 /\/:/  /
 \::/__/
  \:\__\
   \/__/

      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\ \  \
  _\:\~\ \  \
 /\ \:\ \ \__\
 \:\ \:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/











      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/











      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\__\____
 /:/\:::::\__\
 \/_|:|~~|~
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
     \|__|
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \:\~\:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\ \/__/
    \:\__\
     \/__/
      ___
     |\__\
     |:|  |
     |:|  |
     |:|__|__
     /::::\__\
    /:/~~/~
   /:/  /
   \/__/













      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
       \/__/


      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/_|::\/:/  /
    |:|::/  /
    |:|\/__/
    |:|  |
     \|__|
      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
      \:\  \
      /::\  \
     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /
   \/__/













      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/ \:\__\
 \:\  \ /:/  /
  \:\  /:/  /
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\ \/__/
      \:\__\
       \/__/













      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
      \:\  \
      /::\  \
     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /
   \/__/


      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\  \ ___
 /:/\:\  /\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \:\~\:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\ \/__/
    \:\__\
     \/__/











      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\  \ ___
 /:/\:\  /\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/__\:\/:/  /
      \::/  /
      /:/  /
     /:/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/ \:\__\
 \:\  \  \/__/
  \:\  \
   \:\  \
    \:\__\
     \/__/
      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\__\____
 /:/\:::::\__\
 \/_|:|~~|~
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
     \|__|
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \:\~\:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\ \/__/
    \:\__\
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /::\~\:\  \
 /:/\:\ \:\__\
 \/_|::\/:/  /
    |:|::/  /
    |:|\/__/
    |:|  |
     \|__|
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\ \  \
  _\:\~\ \  \
 /\ \:\ \ \__\
 \:\ \:\ \/__/
  \:\ \:\__\
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/











      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
      \:\  \
      /::\  \
     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /
   \/__/


      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/ \:\__\
 \:\  \ /:/  /
  \:\  /:/  /
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\  \
    /::\  \
   /:/\:\  \
  /:/  \:\  \
 /:/__/ \:\__\
 \:\  \ /:/  /
  \:\  /:/  /
   \:\/:/  /
    \::/  /
     \/__/
      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/  /
  /:/  /
 /:/__/
 \:\  \
  \:\  \
   \:\  \
    \:\__\
     \/__/
      ___
     /\__\
    /:/  /
   /:/__/
  /::\__\____
 /:/\:::::\__\
 \/_|:|~~|~
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
    |:|  |
     \|__|

      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
     /::\__\
  __/:/\/__/
 /\/:/  /
 \::/__/
  \:\__\
   \/__/

      ___
     /\  \
     \:\  \
      \:\  \
      /::\  \
     /:/\:\__\
    /:/  \/__/
   /:/  /
   \/__/
```

Comment: @G_M Sorry.. Didn't realize that you created that page. Added a note now :)

Answer (score -1):

Although your title says bash, you put a Python tag on the question so here is one way to solve this in Python. I had to create an openlearning account to get the text from from your link but I pasted it as the input text below.

- [Input text](https://bpaste.net/show/5379781c4ee8)
- [Output text](https://bpaste.net/show/a667e11c2b3c)

`"MAKING ASCII ART IS A KEY PART OF THE HACKERS TOOLKIT"`

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(.*)(?:::(\d+)::)(.*)')

with open('file_1', 'r') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        m = regex.match(line.rstrip())
        beg, num, end = m.groups()
        d[int(num)] = beg + end

for _, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for making this new input file. I will change the link to make the source more accessible to other viewers

Comment: please give the code to do this work by bash too. I added that part to my question just now